# How to chose dependancy alternative during package installation on Debian

Tags: installation, aptitude, debian-jessie, roundcube

**I want to install Roundcube and use PostgreSQL but Debian wants to install mariadb and mysql as a dependancy.**

Details:

I am trying to install Roundcube which depends on roundcube-core which in turn depends on
 mysql or sqlite or postresql:

```
# aptitude show roundcube-core
...
Depends:...roundcube-mysql (= 1.1.4+dfsg.1-1~bpo8+1) | roundcube-sqlite3 (= 1.1.4+dfsg.1-1~bpo8+1) | roundcube-pgsql (=
     1.1.4+dfsg.1-1~bpo8+1)...
```

I want to use postgresql. When I try to install roundcube-core, apt wants to install mariadb and mysql without asking me which db I want to use.

```
# aptitude install roundcube
The following NEW packages will be installed:
aspell{a} aspell-en{a} dictionaries-common{a} emacsen-common{a} libaspell15{a} libc-client2007e{a} libdbd-mysql-perl{a} libltdl7{a} libmcrypt4{a} libmysqlclient18{a} 
libterm-readkey-perl{a} mariadb-client{a} mariadb-client-10.0{a} mariadb-client-core-10.0{a} mariadb-common{a} mlock{a} mysql-common{a} php-auth{a} php-auth-sasl{a} php-db{a} 
php-http-request{a} php-log{a} php-mail{a} php-mail-mime{a} php-mail-mimedecode{a} php-mdb2{a} php-net-dime{a} php-net-ldap2{a} php-net-ldap3{a} php-net-sieve{a} php-net-smtp{a} 
php-net-socket{a} php-net-url{a} php-soap{a} php5-imap{a} php5-intl{a} php5-mcrypt{a} php5-mysqlnd{a} php5-pspell{a} php5-sqlite{a} roundcube roundcube-core{a} roundcube-mysql{a} 
0 packages upgraded, 43 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/7,850 kB of archives. After unpacking 58.4 MB will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n/?]
```

I think this did not happen before. I might have broken something. What might be the cause?

Note: I am using jessie-backports to install Roundcube.

Answer (score 0):

Afaik, aptitude will install the first one from the list of dependencies. In your case this is `roundcube-mysql`.

To install a different one, simply add it to the install command:

```
aptitude install roundcube roundcube-pgsql+M
```

The `+M`, while not necessary, tells aptitude to mark the `roundcube-pgsql` as automatically installed, like the other dependencies.